# C++ to C# Marshaling

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have following piece of C++ code that needs to be C Sharped.

```
int* pData = new int[128];
for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{ pData[i] = i*2 ;}
```

This **pData** int* is later passed to a function as void*

Now I need to put all this in C#. What I have done is as follows,

```
Int32[] tempData = new Int32[128];
for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{ tempData[i] = i*2 ;}
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(tempData[0]) * tempData.Length;
IntPtr ptrData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.Copy(tempData, 0, ptrData, tempData.Length);
```

Later I pass the ptrData to the C# function.But I get the run time error : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are helping too much, the pinvoke marshaller already does this.  The bug is not in this code, I'd guess that the [DllImport] declaration is bad.  Not that native code needs a lot of help bombing on an AV.  Use the debugger, enable unmanaged code debugging.

Comment: The length at the marshal copy is definetly too short - length is just the size of the array but needs to be multiplier by the size of the int.

Comment: I need a little check if the Marshal trick will remain same for `int* pData = new int[128];` and `int pData[128];` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int size = sizeof(int) * tempData.Length;
IntPtr ptrData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.Copy(tempData, 0, ptrData, size);
```

Should do the trick...

Comment: In the code the last param is correct I guess `Marshal.Copy(tempData, 0, ptrData, tempData.Length);` [ref.msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146629.aspx)